# INNER JOIN taking so long for even simple query

Tags: query-performance, join, oracle-12c

My inner queries when executed independently works fast(<2 sec). I have then applied INNER JOIN on two sub query results and final output takes around 25 minutes.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
tableA.consumer,
tableA.ltm,
tableA.consumer_dpip,
tableA.consumer_dpname,
tableA.consumer_port,
tableB.provider,
tableB.provider_DPIP,
tableB.provider_DPNAME,
CASE when instr(tableB.provider_DPIP, tableA.consumer_dpip) = 0
then  tableB.provider_port
else null end ,  
tableB.endpoint,
tableB.endpoint_port    
FROM
(
select DISTINCT
sender.consumername   AS consumer,
devices.ltmip         AS ltm,
devices.dpip          AS consumer_dpip,
devices.dpname        AS consumer_dpname,
appdevices.port       AS consumer_port
from
vz.t_vz_mapnames                  mapnames,
vz.t_vz_sender                    sender,
vz.t_vz_application_devices       appdevices,
vz.t_vz_device_info               devices  
WHERE
mapnames.sno = sender.parentid
AND appdevices.appid = sender.consumername
AND upper(appdevices.zone) = devices.zone
 AND mapnames.type = 'consumerRoutingTable'
AND appdevices.type = 'Consumer'
AND devices.env = 'Production'
) tableA
inner join
(
select  sender.consumername   AS consumer,
sender.providername   AS provider,
LISTAGG(distinct(devices.dpip), ',') WITHIN GROUP(order by devices.dpip) as provider_DPIP,
LISTAGG(distinct(devices.dpname), ',') WITHIN GROUP(order by devices.dpname) as provider_DPNAME,
appdevices.port as provider_port,
dest.url              AS endpoint,
dest.port             AS endpoint_port
from
vz.t_vz_mapnames                  mapnames,
vz.t_vz_sender                    sender,
vz.t_vz_application_devices       appdevices,
vz.t_vz_device_info               devices,
 vz.t_vz_ep_destination_template   dest
WHERE
mapnames.sno = sender.parentid
AND appdevices.appid = sender.providername
AND upper(appdevices.zone) = devices.zone
AND dest.applicationid = sender.providername
AND mapnames.type = 'consumerRoutingTable'
AND appdevices.type = 'Provider'
AND devices.env = 'Production'
AND dest.env = 'PROD'
 group by sender.consumername,sender.providername,appdevices.port, dest.url, dest.port
)tableB 
on tablea.consumer=tableb.consumer  and tableB.endpoint is not null and tableB.endpoint<>' '
order by tableA.consumer, tableA.ltm
```

Indexes on the tables:-

```
index vz.IDX_SNO on vz.t_vz_mapnames(sno);

index vz.IDX_PID on vz.t_vz_sender(PARENTID);
index vz.IDX_CNAME on vz.t_vz_sender(CONSUMERNAME);
index vz.IDX_PNAME on vz.t_vz_sender(PROVIDERNAME);

index vz.IDX_APPID on vz.t_vz_application_devices(APPID);
index vz.IDX_ZONE on vz.t_vz_application_devices(ZONE);
index vz.IDX_PORT on vz.t_vz_application_devices(PORT);
index vz.IDX_TYPE on vz.t_vz_application_devices(TYPE);

index vz.IDX_DP on vz.t_vz_device_info(DPNAME,DPIP,LTMIP);
index vz.IDX_DPDPIP on vz.t_vz_device_info(DPIP);
index vz.IDX_DPNAME on vz.t_vz_device_info(DPNAME);
```

Execution plan:
[image: plan-1]
[image: plan-2]

Am I doing anything wrong here or do I need compound indexes added ? Any inputs highly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the **execution plans** for both queries and the index definitions you have on each table.

Comment: Just for laughs - was this query generated by an ORM or similar?

Comment: @J.D. I have updated the question now.

Comment: @Vérace I'm not sure how the query is generated, but I found this particular operation running very slow in my application.

Comment: It looks like the part of query which is troubling the performance is this - LISTAGG(distinct(devices.dpip), ',') WITHIN GROUP(order by devices.dpip) as provider_DPIP,
LISTAGG(distinct(devices.dpname), ',') WITHIN GROUP(order by devices.dpname) as provider_DPNAME

If I remove these two from select statement query is executing under 15 seconds.
Do you think indexes aren't working here ?